# The Maximum Possible Number of Different Hadrons

Tags: particle-physics

I’ve been trying to calculate the maximum number of possible different Hadrons – Mesons and Baryons – given there are currently six “flavors” of quarks, each coming in three different primary “colors”. For the Baryons – which are thought to be made up of three quarks, each of a different primary color- the calculation is (6 flavors X 3 colors) X (6 flavors X 2 colors) X (6 flavors X 1 color) for a total of 1296 different possible Baryons (and the same number of anti-Baryons).
For the Mesons, which are thought to be made up of a quark and an anti-quark, one quark of a color and an anti-quark of its corresponding anti-color, the calculation is (6 flavors X 3 colors) X (6 anti-flavors X 1 anti-color) for a total of 108 different possible Mesons (and the same number of anti-Mesons).
This is assuming all Hadron (and anti-Hadron) wave functions must be colorless.
Do I have to include spin and space quantum numbers in the overall wave functions in the calculations, or do they just lead to different states of excitation for each Hadron?

Comment: Why are you counting colours? A proton is a proton, whether it's rgb,brg, gbr or any other combination. And yes, you have to consider the spin configurations. That's why there are way more hadrons than combinations of quark flavours. Protons and $\Delta^+$ particles are both $uud$ baryons, for example.

Comment: @dukwon: Thanks. I think you're right. Back to the drawing board for me.

Comment: Perhaps read this first to understand a bit better how hadrons are categorised http://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/reviews/rpp2014-rev-naming-scheme-hadrons.pdf

Comment: @Duckwon - I saw it after I posted the question. Thanks for the tip though. Also found something on Physics Forums: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-many-hadrons-are-there.464750/